# how to use requests.post() with proxy authentication in python?

Tags: python, proxy, beautifulsoup, http-post, http-get

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

url = "http://www.transtats.bts.gov/Data_Elements.aspx?Data=2" 
proxies = {"http":"xxx.xxx.x.xxx: port"}
auth = HTTPProxyAuth("username", "password")
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, auth=auth)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser") 
viewstate_element = soup.find(id = "__VIEWSTATE").attrs 
viewstate = viewstate_element["value"]
eventvalidation_element = soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION").attrs
eventvalidation = eventvalidation_element["value"]


data =     {'AirportList':"BOS",'CarrierList':"VX",'Submit':'Submit',"__EVENTTARGET":"","__EVENTARGUMENT":"","__EVENTVALIDATION":eventvalidation,"}
r = requests.post(url, proxies, auth, data )
print r
```

This code works fine when I use `requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, auth=auth)`, but what to do when there is some data that has to be sent through `requests.post()` under proxy authentication?

Comment: What problem are you facing while trying to use `requests.post(url, proxies=proxies, auth=auth, data=data)`

Comment: Are you sure it is the proxy authentication that is the problem here?

Comment: Yes, proxy authentication is the real issue here.
@VikasNehaOjha using that gives the error 
"TypeError: post() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)". So it can't be used that way.

Comment: Ok. Try this - `proxies = {'http': 'http://username:password@ip:port', 'https': 'http://username:password@ip:port'}` and then `requests.post(url, proxies=proxies, data=data)`

Answer (score 20):

On behalf of Vikas Neha Ojha so all can see

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://username:password@ip:port', 'https': 'http://username:password@ip:port'}
```

and then

```
requests.post(url, proxies=proxies, data=data)
```