# Setting proxy info using python

Tags: python, r, proxy

I am trying to send requests to a server from a corporate proxy. To do so, I am trying to set proxy info. I am basically trying to do the equivalent of the following R code:

```
set_config(use_proxy(url = "some_url", port = some_port, username = 
"some_user", password = "some_pass"))
```

in Python.

I have tried the following:

```
proxy = 'http://some_user:some_pass@some_url:some_port'
os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy
response = requests.post(url=url, data = data)
```

but it doesn't return the right results. Instead it gives an invalid credentials error. The exact same credentials work in R. What could I be missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your proxy through as a dict like this:

```
    proxy = 'http://some_user:some_pass@some_url:some_port'
    proxies = {
        'http': proxy,
        'https': proxy
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=data, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I tried that and it didn't work. I got the same error as before. What other things could I try?

Comment: It's a long html file. The body contains the following: <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>

Comment: You're certain that your credentials are correct, and that it works in R? That should be working, as referenced in this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692759/how-to-use-requests-post-with-proxy-authentication-in-python/30694179 answered by @Vikas Ojha

Comment: I just double checked and yes, they are correct. I asked a related question here, if it's of any help. The R version works perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081162/unable-to-pass-proper-credentials-to-server-through-corporate-proxy-in-python-b

Comment: I'm sorry Derek, I can't tell you why that's not working for you it "should". Hopefully someone can.

Comment: Is there any way I can bump this up? I am afraid it will get lost in other thousands of posts on stack otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Try also adding some headers:

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0"
}

PROXY_HOST = ""
PROXY_PORT = ""
USERNAME = ""
PASSWORD = ""

proxies = {
  "http": "http://%s:%s@%s:%s" % (USERNAME, PASSWORD, PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT),
  "https": "https://%s:%s@%s:%s" % (USERNAME, PASSWORD, PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT)
}

requests.get(link, headers = headers, proxies = proxies)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I tried and got the same error back. Is there anything else I could try?